# R Creating a p-value matrix with missing values

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling, correlation, p-value

I have a dataframe with many missing NAs. I want to create a correlation matrix with a p-value matrix as shown in this link: [Link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram)

I created the correlation matrix like this:

```
as.data.frame(round(cor(df, use = "pairwise.complete.obs", method = c("spearman")), 1))
```

Now I am trying to create a matrix that shows the p-values for each correlation. I have used this code successfully for other dataframes, which include less NAs.

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j])
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

p.mat <- cor.mtest(df)
```

But now I am getting an error:

> Error in cor.test.default(mat[, i], mat[, j]) :    not enough finite
>   observations

I also tried to use the "Hmisc" package for the rcorr-function. But the package does not load correctly. Any idea how to solve this?

```
structure(list(V1 = c(21L, 18L, 11L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 
10L, 25L, 11L, 24L, 13L, 17L, 30L, 12L, 24L, 27L, 19L, 24L, 14L, 
14L, 10L, 21L, 12L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 18L, 
21L, 9L, 18L, 10L, 21L, 17L, 15L, 6L, 21L, 27L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 
12L, 20L, 11L, 17L, 14L, 22L, 14L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 
11L, 19L, 14L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 29L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 8L, 
28L, 12L, 33L, 20L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 
21L, 14L, 12L, 30L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 
15L, 18L, 23L, 19L, 11L, 18L, 9L, 18L, 17L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 
20L, 17L, 25L, 11L, 25L, 19L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 
13L, 24L, 12L, 23L, 21L, 15L, 18L, 14L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 
11L, 24L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 26L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 23L, 
11L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 19L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 
17L, 17L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 7L, 21L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 11L, 15L, 18L, 
13L, 23L, 16L, 16L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 8L, 19L, 14L, 18L, 13L, 
17L, 16L, 25L, 14L, 22L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 9L, 11L), V2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), V6 = c(5L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V40 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V29 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), V56 = c(0.2, 0, 0, 8.5, 3.1, 0.1, 4.5, 26.6, 1, 0, 0, 1.5, 
3.7, 0, 0, 0.3, 10.8, 0.5, 0, 2.7, 0, 0, 8.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 16.4, 4.2, 3.9, 3.5, 3.1, 0, 9, 16, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7.9, 
0, 3.2, 0.9, 0, 4.2, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
13.1, 0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3.6, 2, 30.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 4.2, 0, 2.6, 0, 
4.8, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.9, 0, 2.9, 0.4, 2.4, 
0, 0, 11.5, 6.3, 0, 0, 0.2, 16.3, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.7, 4.8, 0, 1.8, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1.4, 1.2, 0, 
0, 1.4, 0, 1.1, 0, 1.7, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 
0, 2.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 1.4, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 12, 0, 0, 4.9, 4.8, 
0.2, 0.9, 1.6, 7.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 2.8, 0, 2.2, 0, 0, 2.8, 
0, 0.6, 0.3, 0, 9.9, 2.8, 0.8, 0.1), V62 = c(28.8, 19.5, 26, 
29.8, 13, 7.1, 22.6, 11, 21.2, 0.1, 31.7, 7.2, 5.3, 18.4, -1.4, 
0.9, 3.2, 5, 31.9, 8.7, 7.9, 30.6, 7.9, 17.2, 24.7, 26.1, 22, 
29, -6.3, 30.9, 5.7, 11.7, 28.1, 22.9, 12.2, 29.7, 2.7, 5.5, 
19.7, 17.8, 24, 28.6, 24.4, 20, 29.1, 13.7, 8.7, 12, 8.8, 10.4, 
9.7, 10, 19.6, -0.5, 25.6, 17.9, 14.2, 12, 3.6, 2.9, 5.9, 26.7, 
8.7, 20.9, 0.8, 10.5, 14.3, 19.5, -0.3, 28.8, 26.5, 4.9, -0.5, 
23.8, -1.3, 12.1, 2.4, 17.2, 22.1, 23.5, 17, -0.9, 19.3, 4.9, 
20.1, 12.2, 10.8, 31.6, 26.1, 2.5, 26.7, 7.5, 8.2, 11.8, 22.3, 
28.3, 21.4, 25.4, -0.4, 11.4, 27, 9.3, 23.6, 19.9, 23.5, 19.2, 
6.7, 18.9, 2.8, 28, 9.6, 15.2, 13.1, 0, 22.7, 5.7, 3, 4.7, 9.9, 
21.9, -1.6, 19, 11, 17.2, 12.9, 27.4, 21.5, 14.3, 4.5, 6.1, 23.1, 
-0.1, 5.1, 18.7, 3.7, 10.1, 22.6, 16.1, 7.9, 0.9, 30.8, 2.6, 
30.3, 25.9, 20.5, 5.2, 26.9, 22.9, 24.8, 19.6, 10.7, 14.9, 21.9, 
24.5, 21, 11.3, 1.5, 17.6, -8.8, 5.3, -1.2, 29.1, 22.6, 6.7, 
24.6, 22.2, 1.9, 12.8, 19.6, 20.5, 15, 2.9, 27.2, 16.5, -1.4, 
17.1, 8.2, 16, 4.2, 6.6, 19.8, -4.8, 21.7, 27.7, 4.3, 0.4, 25.4, 
27.2, 28.7, 17.9, 22.7, 8.9, 22.1, 16.3, 5.4, 15.3, 9.9, 30.2, 
14.7, 14.2), V73 = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.09275986, NA, NA, 0.52943606, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.39573934, NA, NA, 0.06665112, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.09889552, 
NA, NA, 0.52411667, NA, NA, 0.0786277, 0.39117113, NA, 0.30804176, 
NA, 0.4984171, NA, NA, 0.69054695, 0.61838979, NA, 0.49298138, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.44718356, NA, 0.24114516, 0.00855375, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.31341432, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.38816502, NA, 0.69810769, NA, NA, NA, 0.46607416, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.39012246, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.42507386, NA, NA, -0.26830461, NA, NA, 0.29439447, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.18582551, -0.00246774, 0.33244636, 0.26097549, NA, NA, 
0.56932173, NA, 0.33573443, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.74612433, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02980432, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.60470877, 
NA, NA, 0.29230953, NA, -0.11296095, 0.09783287, NA, NA, 0.32181372, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.3255947, 0.4099077, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.42345733, 0.29293533, NA, 0.52832981, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.55373453, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4070331, 
NA, 0.30780722, 0.59547858, NA, NA, 0.66333634, NA, 0.38209532, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.35778449, NA, NA), V77 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.45406227, NA, 0.87348132, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.78536916, NA, -0.01870051, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.00150528, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.49992833, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.12002325, -0.16249647, NA, 0.51132754, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.20643247, 0.59529347, NA, 0.32442411, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.80611793, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.75247001, 
0.65079036, NA, NA, 0.29773326, -0.2164507, NA, NA, 0.36336748, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.49664945, NA, NA, NA, 0.35610758, NA, NA, NA, 
0.3734933, NA, 0.58752714, NA, NA, NA, -0.38266847, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.28871445, NA, 0.05455121, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0408944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.87592639, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.28923257, NA, NA, NA, -0.16730842, 
NA, -0.122933, 0.25704385, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.92475694, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.15886697, 0.51925536, NA, NA, 0.25372613, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.89195925, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.60877514, NA, 0.33866615, NA, NA, 0.60955791, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.05461735, NA, NA, 0.33697054, 
NA, -0.12079077, -0.14805299, -0.24541818, NA, 0.36340054, NA
), V81 = c(NA, NA, -0.08490089, NA, 0.0555794, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.22856711, NA, -0.57790508, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04856018, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.38039271, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.63132241, -0.35266074, NA, 0.01961822, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.34551275, -0.39085104, NA, -0.27725445, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.21599455, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-0.19924471, -0.18365343, NA, NA, -0.53484587, -0.32543563, NA, 
NA, -0.19992419, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.18500223, NA, NA, NA, -0.12990151, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.39083879, NA, -0.59264661, NA, NA, NA, 0.13154274, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.23261324, 
NA, -0.03944042, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.22193873, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.20022085, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08615186, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.74607469, NA, 0.23032189, 0.0449706, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.04848046, NA, NA, NA, -0.6370161, -0.02900035, 
NA, NA, -0.23145663, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.14884929, NA, NA, NA, 0.22450133, 
NA, 0.24769837, NA, NA, -0.29667428, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.03071992, NA, NA, 0.07786378, NA, 0.23027039, 
-0.20214392, -0.3032353, NA, -0.47432158, NA), V89 = c(0.0834995, 
0.00066815, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02511399, NA, NA, NA, 0.052432, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.14814967, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.33114922, 0.34514567, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.19468406, NA, NA, NA, 
-0.38972029, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.23425484, 
NA, -0.11003854, NA, -0.26367322, NA, NA, 0.29238575, 0.07886438, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.15248164, NA, -0.15641155, NA, NA, -0.08752716, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.34809891, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.27401719, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.32273288, NA, 0.02669399, NA, 0.0727079, 
0.08290143, NA, -0.16476099, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.1029079, -0.11614262, 
NA, NA, -0.14913232, NA, -0.29380582, -0.537503, 0.11869562, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.17315201, NA, 0.10272535, 0.0932595, 0.0793467, 
-0.0845297, NA, NA, NA, -0.02889606, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.15552849, 
0.04599214, NA, 0.19864881, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.11474285, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.10901186, NA, NA, NA, 0.13339891, NA, 0.07056403, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.25760406, 0.2062942, -0.00981489, 
0.3282743, 0.06509166, NA, NA, NA, -0.26049214, NA, -0.13281234, 
NA, 0.32791015, -0.13518787, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.05660112, NA, NA, 0.12368526, -0.15672689, NA, -0.42175072, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.22635573), V90 = c(-0.04245051, 0.3507695, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.32893767, NA, NA, NA, -0.35288827, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.02734148, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.01271804, -0.26617777, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.37528838, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.14921273, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.46296948, 
NA, -0.20223671, NA, 0.12754582, NA, NA, 0.05006781, 0.22653775, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.26092513, NA, 0.54215354, NA, NA, -0.23136087, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.04596987, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.14239809, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.11650203, NA, 0.17058915, NA, -0.18403288, 
0.10295627, NA, -0.15530088, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.45405281, -0.10929859, 
NA, NA, 0.14782657, NA, -0.15852471, -0.05266618, -0.18175069, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.11917474, NA, 0.16136416, -0.14499177, -0.17504283, 
0.13272865, NA, NA, NA, -0.17429991, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.22030747, 
0.29022488, NA, 0.05889091, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.30446594, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.23796595, NA, NA, NA, 0.14051101, NA, -0.05704354, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.25256272, -0.14193822, 0.06924969, 
0.00445279, 0.29815696, NA, NA, NA, 0.25643083, NA, 0.35649173, 
NA, -0.25180143, -0.05787895, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.03069952, NA, NA, -0.18662018, -0.15144552, NA, 0.06595208, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.32091592)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V6", "V40", "V29", "V56", "V62", "V73", "V77", "V81", "V89", 
"V90"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -200L))
```

Comment: I am not sure about the spearman...I tried all different methodes and didnt find any difference.  The percentage is pretty high, many columns are pretty much complete with exception from the last few, which contain exactly 75% of missing data (due to seasons, values are only available for 1 season).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because you need at least 3 non NA in each pair of data.
To solve this, you may want to set p-value = NA when you find an error like this. You can use this variation of the function:

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
            for (j in (i + 1):n) {
                    error <- try(tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j]),
                                 silent =T)
                    if (class(error) == "try-error") {
                            p.mat[i, j] <- NA
                    } else {
                            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
                    }
            }
    }
    colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
    p.mat
 }
```